# Bluetooth (BLE) device not appears in Ionic Capacitor App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, capacitor

I have an Ionic Capacitor application with the @capacitor-community/bluetooth-le plugin. The operating system detects the beacon, but my app does not. The issue only occurs on devices with Android 13.

This is my ionic info output

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.5 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.5.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 17.0.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 17.0.1
   @angular/cli                  : 17.0.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 9.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 5.5.1
   @capacitor/android : 5.5.1
   @capacitor/core    : 5.5.1
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 2.0.0)   : 1.7.4

System:

   NodeJS : v20.9.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 10.1.0
```

This is my Java version
java version "1.8.0_361"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_361-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.361-b09, mixed mode)

This is my app.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { BleClient } from '@capacitor-community/bluetooth-le';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isLocationEnabled: any;
  isBLEEnabled: any;
  deviceId: any;
  ble: boolean = false;
  devices: any[] = [];
  response: any;

  constructor(
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
  try {
    if (Capacitor.getPlatform() == 'android'){
      this.isLocationEnabled = await BleClient.isLocationEnabled();
    } else {
      this.isLocationEnabled = true;
    }
    await BleClient.initialize();
    this.isBLEEnabled = await BleClient.isEnabled();
    if (this.isBLEEnabled && this.isLocationEnabled) {
      this.ble = true;
      this.startScanning();
    }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  startScanning() {
      BleClient.requestLEScan({ allowDuplicates: false }, (res1) => {
        console.log('Device found', res1)  
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "The operating system detects the beacon" you mean you found the beacon via the android system settings? Have you tried searching for the beacon using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: Yes, via system setting the beacon is detected and is detected also by the iBeacon app, but not in my ionic app

Comment: Can the beacon be detected by nRF Connect?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at the [bluetooth-le capacitor plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le)s GitHub page and found something interesting that might explain your problem:

The installation guide contains a section regarding [Bluetooth Permissions for Android 12 and above](https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le#optional-android-12-bluetooth-permissions) that mentions the androidNeverForLocation flag with this hint:

> Note: If you include neverForLocation in your android:usesPermissionFlags, some BLE beacons are filtered from the scan results.

This is also explained in the [Android Guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions#assert-never-for-location).

My guess is that you did set the flag and therefore the beacon can not be found.

Comment: I tried with and without ehis flag and the same result

Comment: Have you tried searching the beacon using nRF Connect? Is it reachable?

Comment: Yes, nRF Connect is detecting the beacon

Comment: Did you gave your app the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission when trying without the flag? I believe location is a permission that needs to be asked at runtime, only setting the permission is not enough

Comment: Yes, is requested and accepted

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas... Maybe create an issue here: https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le/issues